# Using @ngrx/store and @ngrx/core with System.js module loader

Tags: angular, ngrx

In order to use @ngrx/store [ 2.2.1 ] and @ngrx/core [ 1.2.0 ] for state management in my sample Angular 2 [2.4.0] application I followed below steps

1. Installed @ngrx/store [ 2.2.1 ] and @ngrx/core
2. Added below import to root module

   ```
   import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
   ```

3 Added below code in packages section of systemjs.config.js  file

```
 '@ngrx/core': {
          main: 'bundles/core.umd.js',
          format: 'cjs'
      },
      '@ngrx/store': {
          main: 'bundles/store.umd.js',
          format: 'cjs'
      }
```

I am getting below error in browser console , when I browse to the website

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "http://localhost:62818/@ngrx/store/bundles/store.umd.js"

Any idea what needs to be modified to fix this issue.

Comment: You get this error because it is not available at this URL. Nobody but you know why you specified the file that doesn't exist at web root.

Comment: @ estus , it's not like I have added a script tag for this file in .html file..I have only included an import in my module file.

Comment: The file requested by SystemJS (@ngrx/store/bundles/store.umd.js). should be available at web root. If it's not there, this will result in 404. This is as simple as that. You've omitted your server side, but it matters here. It doesn't have to do anything with Angular in particular.

Comment: @estus , you are correct , this was path issue ,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @ estus mentioned , this was a path issue . Adding below lines to map section with correct path resolved the issue

```
'@ngrx/core': 'node_modules/@ngrx/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
'@ngrx/store': 'node_modules/@ngrx/store/bundles/store.umd.js',
```